# CakePHP 2.0 Account validation

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp, authentication

I'm trying to create a simply login page. I want validation on that page so that when a user clicks login the site checks that in the users database activated is set to 1, if not they can't login. I'm still very new to cakephp and am trying to pick up quickly so I'm sorry if this is a simple beginner question.

here is the validation in my User model

```
public $checkActive = array(
    'activated'=>array(
            'rule'=>array('equalTo', '0'),
            'message'=>'The account must be activated, please check your email.'
        ));
```

here is the login function in my usersController

```
 public function login() {

    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Individual Registration');
    $this->set('stylesheet_used', 'style');
    $this->set('image_used', 'eBOXLogo.jpg');


    if ($this->request->is('post')){
    if ($this->request->data['User']['password'] == 'qazwsx'){
    if ($this->Auth->login()){
     if (0 === $this->User->find('count',array('conditions'=>array('enabled'=>1,'login'=> $username)))) {
         $this->Session->setFlash('Sorry, your account is not validated yet.');
    }

        $this->Auth->user('id');
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect('eboxs/home')); 
        }   
    } 
    else {

        $this->Session->setFlash('Username or password is incorrect');
    }
    }else{
    $this->Session->setFlash('Welcome, please login');
    }


}
```

here is my beforeLogin function in  the usersController

```
 public function beforeLogin(){

    if(isset($this->data['User']['password'])){
        $this->data['User']['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data['User']['password']);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

app controller

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    public $components = array(
        'DebugKit.Toolbar',
        'Session', 
        'Auth'=>array(
            'loginRedirect'=>array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'login'),
            'logoutRedirect'=>array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'login'),
            'authError'=>"You can't access this page",
            'authorize'=>array('Controller')
        )
    );

    public function isAuthorized($user){
        return true;
    }

    public function beforeFilter(){
    $this->Auth->allow('index','view');
    $this->set('logged_in', $this->Auth->loggedIn());
    $this->set('current_user',$this->Auth->user());

    }
```

I realize that there is no call in my controller to the validation but with my other validation such as username is unique, I haven't had to call it.

in short at the moment anyone can log into my page, I'm trying to make it so only those who have 1 in the activated field in the users table can login.

Comment: Why are you checking the password manually? Please post your Auth component setup (should be in your AppController)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to check account validation right after login like this :

```
<?php
if ($this->request->is('post')){
if ($this->request->data['User']['password'] == 'qazwsx'){
if ($this->Auth->login()) {

    // login ok, but check if activated
    $username = $this->request->data['User']['username'];
    if (0 === $this->User->find('count',array('conditions'=>array('activated'=>1,'username'=> $username)))) {
         $this->Session->setFlash('Sorry, your account is not validated yet.');
         $this->redirec($this->referer());
    }

    $this->Auth->user('id');
    $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect('eboxs/home')); 
    }   
}
```

Comment: this code blocked everyone from signing in, including those who's activated =1

Comment: also no setflash came up, it came up with a database error saying we were missing a view for pdo.ctp in the error views

Comment: ok, updated the code from 'true' to '1', for 'activated' field, and put a referer() redirect in place.

Comment: still no luck, ill upload my new function

Comment: watch out : it is not "enabled" but "activated"... also corrected the "login" field in "username". be careful to update the whole 'if (0==...' block

Comment: ok the activated user logs  but the non activated user doesnt receive a flash message

Answer (score 1):

Add a `scope` option to your auth setup:

```
'Auth'=>array(
        'loginRedirect'=>array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'login'),
        'logoutRedirect'=>array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'login'),
        'authError'=>"You can't access this page",
        'authorize'=>array('Controller'),
        'scope' => array('User.activated' => 1)
    )
```

This will prevent the user from logging in if they do not have `User.activated = 1`.

Also, look into your [auth setup and re-read the manual page for CakePHP 2.0](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html), you config looks like 1.3. There should be no need to check the password yourself, and you definitely don't need a `beforeLogin` method for such a simple setup.

Comment: this will prevent logging but does not contain any clue as why it is not logged